# How do you force Eclipse to prompt you to create a getter and setter when it doesn't do it automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation

I added two private fields to my Java class.

Eclipse prompted me to automatically create a getter and setter for one of them.

How do I get it to do the same for the other one that it 'forgot' about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

editor view -> right click -> source -> generate getters and setters

Answer (score 5):

Fastest way for people that don't need a mouse anymore: with an editor in focus, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another method: move your cursor over the field definition, press Ctrl+1, and select "create getter and setter for (field)".

Answer (score 3):

To create a getter/setter the fastest way is to type `get` (or `set`) + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and you will see it in the pop-up proposal list.