# Eclipse: How to automatically generate getter when adding a field?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using TDD, and have a very typical coding pattern, using Eclipse to autocreate methods and fields as I code the unit test. For example:

1. type name of method that doesn't exist, e.g:

   `myObj.setValue(someValue);`
2. Click on the little red error mark in the IDE to create the "setValue" method.
3. Type inside of setValue method:

   `public void setValue(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }`
4. Click the red error mark to auto-create a private field (called "value in this case");

So at this point, I would like Eclipse to auto-create the getter method, without having to do it using the *source -> generate getters and setters* menu.

I saw this question: [How do you force Eclipse to prompt you to create a getter and setter when it doesn't do it automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822687/how-do-you-force-eclipse-to-prompt-you-to-create-a-getter-and-setter-when-it-doe) which seems to imply that Eclipse does this, but I couldn't find where to configure that.

Is there some way to configure Eclipse to automatically add setter/getters when adding new private variable?

**UPDATE**: 
To clarify further, I'm looking for something like I saw in the [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo#documentation) documentation. If you take a look at the "How It Works" section, it describes how the framework automatically adds additional methods to your class, whenever you add a private variable. (My preference is not to run another process like that, however, and also not to get all the cruft that it seems to add).  I was hoping Eclipse had something similar.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you use TDD, why create the getter before it is needed? But if you place the cursor after (or before) the set method, write get and then control-space you should get a suggestion for a getter (not exactly what you asked for).

Comment: @RogerLindsjö: That's actually a good question. The main answer is: I added to my *Preferences/Save Actions* the action to "Remove unused private types", so when I save (which happens when I run the unit test to see it fail), Eclipse will remove the field I just created (because it is not yet referenced), making me retype it again.  So it seems the best flow is to just create the getter at that moment.  Also - usually I find that if I create a setter, I usually need getter later on, so it also seems like a good convention that I create it at that moment when I create the setter in any case.

Comment: That explains it then. Had that setting too, but didn't like it, so now I have unused private members as warnings and keep warnings at zero before committing (but accept them during work).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you move your mouse above the name of the variable, you can select "Create getter and setter for varname" in the popup menu.

Or you can create yourself a shortcut to do so. Preferences -> General -> Keys. In the search box you enter "getter" and then you´ll find it.

Comment: At least in Eclipse Helios, you can't select create getter and setter if you already have created the setter when you move the mouse over the variable.

Answer (score 10):

Try this, It works like butter

```
Go to Source --> Generate Getter and Setter Methods

Either select one instance variable, or all ---> Ok
```

Answer (score 5):

I do somewhat differently.

- First create the variable: (say `private int threadsInPool = 3`).
- Place the cursor on the variable name (say `threadsInPool`)
- Apply this shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> (*Press the last <kbd>r</kbd> after a
  slight delay*)
- Just press Enter when *Generate Getters and Setters* dialog shows up and Voila!

**EDIT :**
You can also try using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) annotations:

```
@Getter @Setter private String value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... dunno if this is what you are looking for, but if I create a field in a class there is a warning that the field is unused. If I click on the warning sign the option to generate getter and setter for the field appears:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that question implies that, since all answers gave a manual solution.

AFAIK it's not possible to do automatically without a plugin, and I don't know of a plugin that does it.

I use a template to create artifacts like that all at once, but I don't follow the same path--I'm not sure a template solution would work if a getter or setter already existed, since I'm not sure you can check for the presence of a method and make template decisions based on that. Maybe you can.